# How to get `CompilerOptions` from `tsconfig.json`

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm working with the TypeScript compiler API. When initializing a program, I'm asked to supply a `CompilerOptions` object. I want to use the `CompilerOptions` for a given `tsconfig.json` file, but I can't seem to figure out what the right way is to get this.

I think I'm supposed to use `parseJsonConfigFileContent` but that also needs a `ParseConfigHost`. [They say](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5276#issuecomment-351145208) that it's easy to implement yourself, but particularly the method `readDirectory` seems rather complicated to implement yourself. As far as I can see, you need to return all TypeScript files in a certain directory, accounting for a `excludes` and `includes`.

Surely, TypeScript does this internally somewhere already. How can I use the default `readDirectory` or `ParseConfigHost`?

Phrased in another way: what's the simplest way to get the `CompilerOptions` for a given TypeScript project?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With the following code I was able to easily read the compiler options.

I don't yet know if this has any limitations, but it seems to work fine and it only uses things that Typescript itself provides:

```
const configFileName = ts.findConfigFile(
  "./",
  ts.sys.fileExists,
  "tsconfig.json"
);
const configFile = ts.readConfigFile(configFileName, ts.sys.readFile);
const compilerOptions = ts.parseJsonConfigFileContent(
  configFile.config,
  ts.sys,
  "./"
);
```

Comment: Also, note that this solution doesn't require path to "tsconfig.json"!  `findConfigFile` takes care of that and you can always pass `"./"` there.

Comment: I had issues with this answer resolving "extends" in my tsconfig and I discovered that I needed to pass in `dirname(configFileName)` to `ts.parseJsonConfigFileContent` for `basePath`, instead of just `"./"`. Now it resolves everything properly.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, passing any `CompilerOptions` is *very* buggy. You will lose a ton of your time. What I did, was passing an empty object as `CompilerOptions`. And that's quite enough to get the diagnostics or AST or whatever you need. Unless you need to actually compile programmatically.

Nevertheless, IIRC, I once have managed to pass my compiler options by just reading tsconfig.json with `JSON.encode(fs.readFileSync('./tsconfig.json'))`

Comment: You might need https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5 if your `tsconfig.json` contains comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `tsconfig.json` content in hand, you can easily use `convertCompilerOptionsFromJson`.

For example:

```
const compilerOptions = ts.convertCompilerOptionsFromJson({ module: 'commonjs', outDir: 'dist' }, '.');
console.log(compilerOptions);
```

You'll get the following output:

```
{ options: { module: 1, outDir: 'dist' }, errors: [] }
```