# How to compile tsconfig.json into a config object using TypeScript API?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I am looking for a public official TypeScript API (ideally, of version 4.x) for parsing `tsconfig.json` / `jsconfig.json` files into complete TypeScript configuration objects (by "complete" I mean, all of its properties are filled in with values, – either taken explicitly from the `*.json`, or implicitly from known defaults), as in:

```
import ts from "typescript";

const tsconfig = await ts.parseConfigFile('./tsconfig.json');

tsconfig.compilerOptions.noEmit;
// false
// (or whatever it is set to in *.json)
```

**Is there such kind of function in `typescript` npm package?** I couldn't find it myself, both in [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/) and in IntelliSense suggestions (the ones invoked by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>).

I have seen [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55298251/4554883) with the same kind of request, but *a)* it is unanswered, *b)* the [link in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298251/programmatically-compile-typescript-from-tsconfig-json#comment97324878_55298251) references a [5.5-year-old solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6387#issuecomment-169739615), – there's *gotta* be a change in API since then.

---

In reality, I need only a handful of properties from the config file, so it would be relatively easy to write a couple of helpers to parse the `*.json` file and grab its contents. However:

- there are more exotic use cases (such as [using Project References](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55000497/4554883) and/or [extending parent config object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends)), in which such a solution would not work;
- the aforementioned **.json* objects might have comments and trailing commas, so it is not trivial to even parse the file in the first place;
- it would be weird to rewrite something that is known to be written already.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44573

Answer (score 13):

## Edit

In a comment below, @Hiroki Osame explains that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53898219/4376643) by using `ts.parseJsonConfigFileContent` he was able to get the `extends` followed automatically without any "hand-crafting".

Also on this page here, @Simon Buchan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70013087/4376643) looks to be similarly correct.

## Short Answer

A function to read compiler options from a tsconfig file while correctly handling tsconfig `extends` keyword inheritance

```js
function getCompilerOptionsJSONFollowExtends(filename: string): {[key: string]: any} {
  let compopts = {};
  const config = ts.readConfigFile(filename, ts.sys.readFile).config;
  if (config.extends) {
    const rqrpath = require.resolve(config.extends);
    compopts = getCompilerOptionsJSONFollowExtends(rqrpath);
  }
  return {
    ...compopts,
    ...config.compilerOptions,
  };
}
```

The result of that can be converted to type `ts.CompilerOptions` via

```
const jsonCompopts = getCompilerOptionsJSONFollowExtends('tsconfig.json')
const tmp = ts.convertCompilerOptionsFromJson(jsonCompopts,'')
if (tmp.errors.length>0) throw new Error('...')
const tsCompopts:ts.CompilerOptions = tmp.options
```

## TL;DR

These related functions exist in `typescript@4.3.2`:

```
ts.readConfigFile
ts.parseConfigFileTextToJson
ts.convertCompilerOptionsFromJson
ts.parseJsonConfigFileContent
ts.parseJsonSourceFileConfigFileContent
```

This post only addresses the first three:

### `ts.readConfigFile`

```
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    ts.readConfigFile('./tsconfig.base.json', ts.sys.readFile),
    null,
    2
  )
);
```

where `tsconfig.base.json` has content

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
//comment
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es2020"],// trailing comma
  }
}
```

results in

```
{
  "config": {
    "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "declaration": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "lib": [
        "es2020"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The things to notice here:

1. The config file referenced by extends is not pulled in and expanded.
2. The compiler options are not converted into the internal form required by typescript compiler API functions. (Not of type `ts.CompilerOptions`)
3. Comments are stripped and trailing commas ignored.

### `ts.parseConfigFileTextToJson`

```
const parsed2 = ts.parseConfigFileTextToJson(
  ''/*'./tsconfig.base.json'*/, `
  {
    "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
    // comment
    "compilerOptions": {
      "declaration": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "lib": ["es2020"], // trailing comma
    }
  }
  `);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(parsed2, null, 2));
```

results in

```
{
  "config": {
    "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "declaration": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "lib": [
        "es2020"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The function is the same as `ts.readConfigFile` except that text is
passed instead of a filename.

Note: The first argument (filename) is ignored unless perhaps there is an error. Adding a real filename but leaving the second argument empty results in empty output.  This function can not read in files.

### `ts.convertCompilerOptionsFromJson`

```
  const parsed1 = ts.convertCompilerOptionsFromJson(
    {
      lib: ['es2020'],
      module: 'commonjs',
      target: 'es2020',
    },
    ''
  );
  console.log(JSON.stringify(parsed1, null, 2));
```

results in

```
{
  "options": {
    "lib": [
      "lib.es2020.d.ts"
    ],
    "module": 1,
    "target": 7
  },
  "errors": []
}
```

The value of the `options` property of the result is in the internal format required by typescript compiler API. (I.e. it is of type `ts.CompilerOptions`)

The value (1) of `module` is actually the compiled value of `ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS`, and the value (7) of `target` is actually the compiled value of `ts.ScriptTarget.ES2020`.

### discussion / extends

When `extends` keyword does NOT come into play then
by using the following functions:

- `ts.readConfigFile`
- `ts.convertCompilerOptionsFromJson`

as shown above, you should be able to get what you want.

However, when the `extends` keyword DOES come into play, it is more complicated.  I can find no existing API function to follow extends automatically.

There is, however, a CLI function to do so

```
npx tsc -p tsconfig.base.json --showConfig
```

results in

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es2020"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2020",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./archive/doc-generator.ts",
        "./archive/func-params-exp.ts",
        "./archive/reprinting.ts",
        "./archive/sw.ts",
        ....
        ....
    ]
}
```

where all the files implicitly included are also output.

The following one liner in bash will yield just the compile options -

```
echo 'console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse('\'`npx tsc -p tsconfig.base.json --showConfig`\'').compilerOptions,null,2))' | node
```

results in just the compile options

```
{
  "lib": [
    "es2020"
  ],
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es2020",
  "strict": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "declaration": true,
  "sourceMap": true
}
```

Obviously, invoking CLI from a program is far from ideal.

### how to follow extends using API

Show the principle:

```
const config1 = ts.readConfigFile('./tsconfig.base.json', ts.sys.readFile).config
console.log(JSON.stringify(config1,null,2))
const tsrpath = ts.sys.resolvePath(config1.extends)
console.log(tsrpath)
const rqrpath = require.resolve(config1.extends)
console.log(rqrpath)
const config2 = ts.readConfigFile(rqrpath, ts.sys.readFile).config
console.log(JSON.stringify(config2,null,2))
```

results in

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2020"
    ]
  }
}
/mnt/common/github/tscapi/@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json
/mnt/common/github/tscapi/node_modules/@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Node 14",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2020"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2020",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Note that `require.resolve` resolves to what we want, but `ts.sys.resolve` does not.

Here is a function which returns compiler option correctly inheriting from extends:

```
function getCompileOptionsJSONFollowExtends(filename: string): {[key: string]: any} {
  let compopts: ts.CompilerOptions = {};
  const config = ts.readConfigFile(filename, ts.sys.readFile).config;
  if (config.extends) {
    const rqrpath = require.resolve(config.extends);
    compopts = getCompileOptionsJSONFollowExtends(rqrpath);
  }
  compopts = {
    ...compopts,
    ...config.compilerOptions,
  };
  return compopts;
}
```

Test run -

```
const jsonCompopts = getCompileOptionsJSONFollowExtends('./tsconfig.base.json')
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonCompopts,null,2))
const tsCompopts = ts.convertCompilerOptionsFromJson(jsonCompopts,'')
console.log(JSON.stringify(tsCompopts,null,2))
console.log('');
```

results in

```
{
  "lib": [
    "es2020"
  ],
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es2020",
  "strict": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "declaration": true,
  "sourceMap": true
}
{
  "options": {
    "lib": [
      "lib.es2020.d.ts"
    ],
    "module": 1,
    "target": 7,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "errors": []
}
```

Comment: Very thorough write up! I'm finding that `parseJsonConfigFileContent` resolves extends though. eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53898219/911407

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat confusingly, you should use `ts.getParsedCommandLineOfConfigFile()`:

```
> ts.getParsedCommandLineOfConfigFile('tsconfig.json', {}, ts.sys)
{
  options: {
    moduleResolution: 2,
    module: 99,
    target: 6,
    lib: [ 'lib.es2019.d.ts' ],
    types: [ 'node' ],
    strict: true,
    sourceMap: true,
    esModuleInterop: true,
    importsNotUsedAsValues: 2,
    importHelpers: true,
    incremental: true,
    composite: true,
    skipLibCheck: true,
    noEmit: true,
    configFilePath: 'C:/code/.../tsconfig.json'
  },
  watchOptions: undefined,
  fileNames: [
    'C:/code/.../src/index.tsx',
...
```

The third parameter is actually a `ts.ParseConfigFileHost`, so you should probably manually implement that (using implementations from `ts.sys`)

You can also use `ts.parseJsonFileContent(tsconfigContent, ts.sys, baseDir, {}, errorMessageFileName)` if you have already parsed the config, for example, when it's inline in some larger config file.

Answer (score -1):

I might misunderstand your problem, but should it not suffice to load the content `tsconfig.json` file and parse it with `JSON.parse`?

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const txt = fs.readFileSync('./tsconfig.json');
try {
   const obj = JSON.parse(txt);
   console.log(obj);
} catch (e) {
   console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the config file is an invalid JSON (and it might be due to comments and trailing commas)

Comment: Well, standard JSON must be valid and does not support comments. If you want to support comments, you can use a custom JSON parser like https://www.npmjs.com/package/comment-json if you want to allow comments.  If you want to check for errors you might just use a try/catch.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4987

Comment: If you question is specific to the tsconfig parser build into TypeScript, I've misunderstood. I only remember the `parseConfigFileTextToJson` function that you already used.