# Convert TS Config to Typescript TranspileOptions

Tags: typescript

I am new to transpiling TypeScript to JavaScript programmatically. So far, I am using TypeScript's `transpileModule()` function. This function takes a source string and transpiler options.
I wanted to pass my `tsconfig.json` file as transpiler options, but this does not work, because there are slight differences (e.g. `tsconfig.json` uses string enums, wherease the compiler options use JavaScript `enum` enums).

Is there an easy way to convert between the two formats, e.g. like this:

```
transpileModule(tsString, configTsToTranspilerOptions(tsConfigJson));
```

Comment: What about requiring this file, then taking its `compilerOptions` value?

Comment: That's what I did. But the required `compilerOptions` is incompatible to the `CompilerOptions` interface. E.g. in `tsconfig.json`, the property `jsx` is a string, but in `CompilerOptions` it is an `enum`.

Comment: Is this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956755/how-to-compile-tsconfig-json-into-a-config-object-using-typescript-api - helpful? Checking the code shows that it returns `any` though, and not `CompilerOptions`.